# Regex to remove Key/Value in a JSON Object

Tags: arrays, json, regex, lexical-analysis

I have a JSON like below:

`{"queueNumber": "123","field":"name",UserId":[12,12,34],"cur":[{"objectName":"test","uniqueNumber":"123456"}]}`

I want to remove the key-value pairs if it matches **key or value** matches the given field.

I am using the below regex.It is not removing the key if the type of value is an Array. `ex: UserId":[12,12,34]`

`(,\s*"(queueNumber|name|uniqueNumber|cur|UserId)\d*":\s*(".*?"|\d+.\d+|\w+))|("(queueNumber|name|uniqueNumber|cur|UserId)\d*":\s*(".*?"|\d+.\d+|\w+)(\s*,)?)`

current output:

`{"UserId":[12,12,34],"cur":[{"objectName":"test"}]}`

Expected output:

`{"cur":[{"objectName":"test"}]}`

It's quite obvious that regex is not an ideal way to get this. But, currently we have to fix this using regex.
How to improve this regex to handle this case?

I have very minimal knowledge about regex. So, I am seeking out here for help.

Thanks in advance!

Note: I have to remove it using Regular Expressions and not using any other language. Please don't post any of those answers or mark this as a possible duplicate question.

Comment: Why do you have to use regex? Why not more simply parse the JSON and then deal with Java objects?

Comment: @depperm it has to handle all the cases ex: UserId (12,13,15) or "key":["str1","str2"] or "key":[{"k":"v"}]

Comment: Question.  _"cur"_ is within the group of matching keys.  Thus, an output would actually be _{"field":"name"}_.  Is this intended, or should _"cur"_ be removed from the keys list?

Answer (score 1):

The 'regular' in 'regular expression' isn't some random word. It refers specifically to the notion of a [**Regular Grammar**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar). As in, **Regular Expressions can only be used to parse things written in a Regular Grammar**, and, crucially, [**JSON is not a Regular Grammar**](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language).

Hence, you cannot parse the with REs.

You were asked to. Okay. What if I ask you to break the speed of light? or make 2+2 equal to 5? The answer is simply: **You were asked to do something that is impossible to do**.

You can add a bunch of clauses on JSON to make it regular, but then, it would no longer be JSON. You could also write an RE-based JSON parser/modifier which simply does the wrong thing for certain inputs, but then you'd have an improper algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

As @rzwitserloot points out, the general case can't be done.

In your case, the specific case can be done.  (At least, if your example is truly representative.)

Change
`(".*?"|\d+.\d+|\w+)`
to
`(".*?"|\[[\d,]+\]|\d+.\d+|\w+)`.

I would then go back and review the third and fourth clauses there.
The third probably should have been `\d+\.\d+`, and might justify adding variant `\d+`.  On the other hand, maybe you meant to also catch `1E10`, but not `1.1E10`.
The fourth should only be matching select keywords (`true`, `false`, `null`), so you should probably just name them.